# To define several areas (with no polygonal shape) in a web page

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I was wondering if it was possible to define several areas in a web page. I'm not talking about the classic rectangular division (made by "div"), but something more: to define areas of various shapes, maybe not polygonal, as, for instance, in the picture below.

[image: web page divided in not polygonal shapes]

I don't know lots of things:

- I don't know if it's possible;
- I don't know if it's a good practice according to the GUI creation theory;
- I don't know if, in case it was possible to built something like this, it's also compatible with the majority of browsers (I don't mind).

Building a page like this, maybe, is a crazy thing and, in my inexperience, I don't know. I'm just trying to understand the potentiality and the limits of html and css in this sense.

Thank you.

Comment: CSS is all about rectangles.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's useful to know that there's a limit like this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create circle DIV using CSS this way (for example):

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.circle2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

and usign this CSS in your DIVs:

```
<div class="circle circle1"></div>

<div class="circle circle2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Old School way of doing that... image maps, but a whole site not feasible standards was afaik

Answer (score 1):

Most elements are rectangles, but there are options like "border-radius" to make an element look and behave like a circle. Just google for "CSS Circles"; you will find blogs like this: http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles

Another more complex and powerful way is using "canvas" in HTML5. You can define your custom shapes, just look for this site: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Last but not least you can use SVG images. I don't know, what you're going to do, but in some cases (just for displaying scaleable elements without interaction) it works great.